# How to get the type of the current endpoint contract?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a message inspector in which I am trying to get the type of contract for the current endpoint. I want to reflect on the type but `GetType` returns null.

```
var contractType = Type.GetType(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.ContractName);
if (contractType != null)
{
    foreach (var member in contractType.GetMembers())
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I am guessing because `OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.ContractName` holds the name of the interface instead of the fully qualified type name it can't get the type. My config has the fully qualified type name so I'm not sure why .NET is doing that. Is there another way I can get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the correct type via:

```
OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Type
```

See MSDN:
[DispatchRuntime.Type - Gets or sets the contract type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.type.aspx)

Comment: This gets the type of service but I needed the contract type. It lead me in the right direction though. I was able to get it by doing this -                         var im = OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Type.GetInterfaceMap(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Type.GetInterface(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.ContractName)); and then I can get the methods from im.InterfaceMethods. Thanks.
                        {